# Проблема с SimpleSearch на MODx ( Не появляется страница результатов .. )

Tags: modx, поиск

Здравствуйте. Достаточно много гуглил но так и не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос.
Использую на сайте SimpleSearch для создания "поиска".

Вот такой код использовал на странице "Результаты поиска" :

```
[[SimpleSearch? &amp;tpl=`SearchResulttpl` &amp;includeTVs=`1` 
&processTVs=`1` ]]
```

Вот мой чанк SearchResulttpl :

```
<p class="sisea-results">[[+resultInfo]]</p>

<div class="sisea-paging"><span class="sisea-result-pages">
[[%sisea.result_pages? &namespace=`sisea` &topic=`default`]]</span>
[[+paging]]</div>

<div class="sisea-results-list">
    [[+results]]
</div>

<div class="sisea-paging"><span class="sisea-result-pages">
[[%sisea.result_pages? &namespace=`sisea` &topic=`default`]]</span>
[[+paging]]</div>
```

И собственно SearchFormtpl:

```
<form class="sisea-search-form" action="[[~[[+landing]]]]" method="
[[+method]]">
<div class="search" style="position: relative;">
<input type="text" name="[[+searchIndex]]" id="[[+searchIndex]]" value="
[[+searchValue]]" placeholder="Поиск по сайту ..." />
<span class="search-descr">
   Используйте поисковой запрос, например: <em>Порошковый огнетушитель</em>
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="[[+landing]]" /> 

<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 30px; z-
index: 100; opacity: 0; width: 40px; background-color: #000;" value="
[[%sisea.search? &namespace=`sisea` &topic=`default`]]" />
</div>
</form>
```

Работает следующим образом - при вводе запроса, нажимаем на enter либо саму кнопку submit, запрос в поле очищается, а вот никакая другая страница не открывается, в консоли ни одной ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема, может что-то не учел или неправильно написал ?

Answer (score 0):

Сниппет необходимо было вызывать некешируемым (с восклицательным знаком)

```
[[!SimpleSearch? 
    &tpl        = `SearchResulttpl` 
    &includeTVs = `1` 
    &processTVs = `1` 
]]
```